# How to call jQuery click function on a tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, click, haml

```
%ul.nav.nav-tabs
  %li.active
  %a{ :href => "#a", "data-toggle" => "tab" }
  %li
  %a{ :href => "#b", "data-toggle" => "tab" }
```

How can I call jQuery click function on the second tab?

Answer (score 2):

```jquery
$('.nav-tabs li').eq(1).click(function(){alert("test")})
```

or if you want to call `click` event:

```jquery
$('.nav-tabs li').eq(1).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#b').parent().click(function(){alert("test")});
```

I think this is what you mean.

Comment: #b is the value of the href attribute, not the ID. You could change your selector to $("[href='#b']").click(...) the parent is an LI, you would want to trigger the click on the anchor itself.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Using # as an id in jquery is just so natural.  that makes it way more difficult.  If you can add id's to the items above, that should make it way more solvable.